# Expected win in a lottery

Tags: probability-theory

In  a  lottery  $1000$  tickets  are  sold  and  the  cost  of a  ticket  is  if  $10$dollars.  The  lottery  offers  a  first  prize of  if  $1,000\,$ dollars,  two  second  prizes  of   $500\,$ dollars each,  and three  third  prizes  of $100$ dollars  each.  A  person purchases  a  ticket.  If  $X$  denotes  the  amount  he may  get,  find  $E(X)$  and  $V(X)$. 
My try
X belongs to {$1000,500,100$}
$P(X=1000)=\frac {1}{1000}$

$P(X=500)=\frac {2}{1000}$

$P(X=100)=\frac {3}{1000}$
And $E (X)=2.3$
Please can somebody help

Comment: $X \in \{1000,500,100,0\}$
What are the chances you get nothing?

Comment: Whatever be the chances when we want the expextation it just becomes 0 because of the multiplication by 0

Comment: OK, What exactly is your question. I'm not sure where you need help.

Comment: What you've done looks OK, but it's possible the correct answer is $E(X)=-\$7.70$, because the ticket *costs* $\$10$.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X=990) = \frac{1}{1000}$$
$$P(X=490) = \frac{2}{1000}$$
$$P(X=90) = \frac{3}{1000}$$
$$P(X=-10) = \frac{994}{1000}$$

Note I've subtracted $10$ from each of the values since regardless of the outcome, we lost $10$ dollars by buying a ticket. Here, $X$ is our net *gain* rather than our *winnings*; if you care about the latter, just add $10$ to $E(X)$ and leave $V(X)$ alone (I'll leave you to think about why this is true).

We have:

$$E(X) = \sum_{X}{(X \ P(X))}$$

$$V(X) = \sum_{X}{((X - E(X))^2 \ P(X))}$$

We have four values for $X$, namely $-10,90,490,990$, so we can just sum over these four values.

This gives us $E(X) = -7.7$, $V(X) = 1524$